# PHP strip_tag for tags with specific ID's

Tags: php, html

Does anyone know how to strip_tag for a specific ID?

For example what if i want to remove the example2 fieldset tag below?

```
<td> <fieldset disabled id="example1"> content here </fieldset>
</td>
<td> <fieldset disabled id="example2"> content there </fieldset>
</td>
```

Comment: strip_tags() is pretty basic stuff, you need a DOM parser for that task